# Statistical test for random machine learning classifier algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance

Many optimization algorithms, such as stochastic gradient descent algorithm, are based on random processes. 
Assume that I am using one classifier that uses the SGD,
What statistical tests are required to validate the results, e.g., the accuracy?

Does running the algorithm $n$ times and the find the average of all $n$ accuracies enough?

Is there any other standard method that gives a statistical significance for the classification in such scenario?

Comment: Down-voting without a comment deserves a down-vote, too.

Comment: Think about what you are comparing your classifier's accuracy to? Random prediction?